# $(e^z)^w = e^{zw}$ for complex $z,w$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to reason out the justification for why, if $z,w\in\mathbb C$, then $(i^z)^w=i^{zw}$.  I believe there may be some kind of point in the justification where you have to be careful, because we know that

$$\sqrt{1} = \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1} = i\cdot i = -1$$

is a fallacious argument because square-roots (which are 1/2 powers) do not always distribute.

On the other hand, we have an argument that $e^{z+w} = e^ze^w$ which goes: This equation is valid for real $z,w$.  Now set $z$ to be any fixed real number so that $f(w)=e^{z+w}$ is an entire function and so is $f(w) = e^ze^w$.  Since these agree for all real $w$ then they agree for all complex $w$. Now fix $w$ as any complex value, and repeat the argument for $z$.

I've been trying to see how I could reproduce something similar for $(i^z)^w = i^{zw}$, but I'm not sure the argument still works here.  Do we know that the expression is even valid for real $z,w$?  I can't think of an easy justification.  Do we have to do something like: Define $f(z) = z^z$, which is defined for (positive) real values, and we extend it to the complex plane.  But having done so, I don't see how to relate this back to the law $(i^z)^w = i^{zw}$ since $z,w$ may not be $i$.

---

I am asking this in particular because of this argument: https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/what-is-i-to-the-power-of-i-T/

In this the author seems to freely assume that $(e^{i\pi/2})^i = e^{i^2\pi/2}$ and I'm not sure if that's justified.

Comment: If you take the power series as the definition, then the property holds as long as complex multiplication commutes (which it does)

Comment: You're considering $i^z$ as a multi-valued function, right? The same applies to $(e^z)^w$, so, no, your equality won't hold. What is the definition of $a^w$ for $a\ne 0$?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of $a^b$ for complex $a$ and $b$ (with $a \ne 0$) is

$$a^b = \exp(b \log a)$$

But any of the branches of the logarithm could be used, so this is a multivalued function.
Note that $\log \exp(z) = z + 2 \pi i n$ where $n$ is an integer.

Thus
$$\exp(z)^w = \exp(w \log \exp(z)) = \exp(w (z + 2 \pi i n)) = \exp(wz) \exp(2 \pi i n w)$$

One of the possible values (e.g. with $n=0$) is $\exp(wz)$, but if $w$ is not an integer this is not the only one.

Comment: A couple questions: Here does "log" refer to the principal branch? If so, isn't that one-valued and so using that definition, $a^b$ is not multivalued?  I'm guessing the more reasonable interpretation is that we mean "log" to be any analytic branch, but just wanted to confirm.  Second question: I'm not seeing what justifies $\exp(z)^w=\exp(w\log\exp(z))$.

Comment: As I wrote, "any of the branches of the logarithm could be used, so this is a multivalued function."  For the last formula, substitute $a = \exp(z)$ and $b=w$.

Comment: Hi Robert.  I hope that you are well and staying safe and healthy.  You might consider pointing out the distinction between $\exp(z)$, the entire function, and $(e)^z=\text{exp}(z\log(e))=\text{exp}(z)\text{exp}(i2n\pi z)$, a multivalued one..  Students sometimes confuse things due to abuse of notation.